# How can i study stability for a new method that solves second degree non lineara differential equations?

Tags: numerics, nonlinear-equations, differential-equations

I developed a new method to solve this equations $\frac{d{y}^{2}}{dx^{2}}=g(x,y,\frac{dy}{dx})$ for a general g(x,y,z), wich their solution is a function f(x)=y. Obviously you need $y(x_0)=y_0$ and $y'(x_0)=y_1$.

The thing is i do not have a clue how to study stability of solutions, or to see if converges rapidly to the solution, or it's range of aplication. Can someone orientate me? the method first aproximates the function, and then iterates with the data available, wich is the second derivative the first and the value of the function, i don't use taylor aproximations. I programmed it and works perfectly fine.

Comment: The equation is a typical second order ordinary differential equation. Have you looked through any of the books on the numerical solution of ODEs? Say, Hairer & Wanner?

Comment: No. I'll see that. Thanks for the data